# MySQL process stuck in commit state

Tags: mysql, performance

We recently noticed an issue on our MyCluster DB which is comprised of 2 instances hosted on AWS.

Our website grinds to halt in terms of performance and we noticed that there 2 processes that are stuck in commit state as shown below.

```
Id  User    Host    db  Command Time    State   Info
49  rdsadmin    localhost:56378 mysql   Sleep   1       \n
938 dbadmin 10.0.11.242:57130   REDACTED    Query   1   init    COMMIT
942 dbadmin 10.0.1.114:49236    REDACTED    Query   1   init    COMMIT
```

We are in the process of getting performance_schema enabled. How should we go about find the root cause of the performance bottleneck?

Answer (score 1):

We noticed that there were large number of inserts into the error log table coupled with info logging. This put a lot of stress on the database and resulted in significant performance issues. We disabled info logging at the application level which eliminated the performance bottleneck.